# xlc: sizeof of templated class not working

Tags: c++, templates, xlc

I'm using sizeof() inside a template argument, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A>
struct Foo {
    A a;
};

template<class A, size_t S = sizeof(Foo<A>)>
class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {
        // prints 4, as expected
        std::cout << sizeof(Foo<A>) << std::endl;

        // prints 1! why?
        std::cout << S << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Bar<int> foo;
}
```

For some reason xlc++ decides that `sizeof(Foo<A>)` as the default template argument results in 1. Why is that so? is this a compiler bug? It prints 4, 4 in Visual Studio 2015.

I'm using xlc version `z/OS V2.1 XL C/C++`.

Comment: Compiler bug? And also, I can't reproduce it on MSVC, Clang and GCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely a bug in the compiler which has been fixed on AIX but not on Z

Testing latest (i.e. ptf) versions on AIX
V13.1.3 expected result
V13.1 expected result
V12.1 expected result 
V11.1 expected result

On ZOS
V2R1 fails
V2R2 fails

If you report the bug we can get the fix put into V2R1.